# Visual Basic 6 Game "21" not displaying MsgBox when necessary

Tags: vb6

Trying to make the game "21" in visual basic 6, i have everything done but MsgBox is not displaying when its Bust, or Blackjack. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub cmdCheckScore_Click()
lblPC1.Visible = True
lblPC2.Visible = True
lblPC3.Visible = True



End Sub

Private Sub cmdDrawCard_Click()



If lblDraw1.Caption = "" Then 'Draws 3 random numbers with 3 button clicks
intDraw1 = Int(Rnd * 10 + 1)
lblDraw1.Caption = intDraw1
ElseIf lblDraw2.Caption = "" Then
intDraw2 = Int(Rnd * 10 + 1)
lblDraw2.Caption = intDraw2
ElseIf lblDraw3.Caption = "" Then
intDraw3 = Int(Rnd * 10 + 1)
lblDraw3.Caption = intDraw3

End If

intPlayerScore = intPlayer1 + intPlayer2 + intDraw1 + intDraw2 + intDraw3
intComputerScore = intPC1 + intPC2 + intPC3


If intPlayerScore > 21 Then
MsgBox "Bust!"
ElseIf intPlayerScore = 21 Then
MsgBox "Blackjack!"
End If



End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()
Randomize
Dim intPlayer1 As Integer
Dim intPlayer2 As Integer
Dim intPlayer3 As Integer
Dim intPC1 As Integer
Dim intPC2 As Integer
Dim intPC3 As Integer
Dim intDraw1 As Integer
Dim intDraw2 As Integer
Dim intDraw3 As Integer
Dim PlayerScore As Integer
Dim ComputerScore As Integer

intDraw1 = 0
intDraw2 = 0
intDraw3 = 0

intPlayer1 = Int(Rnd * 10 + 1)
intPlayer2 = Int(Rnd * 10 + 1)
lblPlayer1.Caption = intPlayer1
lblPlayer2.Caption = intPlayer2

intPC1 = Int(Rnd * 10 + 1)
intPC2 = Int(Rnd * 10 + 1)
intPC3 = Int(Rnd * 10 + 1)

lblPC1.Caption = intPC1
lblPC2.Caption = intPC2
lblPC3.Caption = intPC3
End Sub
```

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 hours, and still no solution.

Comment: Not C#. Also not vba.

Comment: For getting better assistance, make sure you specify as much as you can about the problem.  Another thing is to narrow it down, which in this case the problem lies in the values being 0 when you expected otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your variables are getting created out of scope, and therefore when the click code runs, they're all variants.

Move your declares out of Form_Load to above cmdCheckScore

`Dim intPlayer1 As Integer 'at the top of your FORM
Dim intPlayer2 As Integer
Dim intPlayer3 As Integer
Dim intPC1 As Integer
Dim intPC2 As Integer
Dim intPC3 As Integer
Dim intDraw1 As Integer
Dim intDraw2 As Integer
Dim intDraw3 As Integer
Dim PlayerScore As Integer
Dim ComputerScore As Integer 'at the top of your FORM
Private Sub cmdCheckScore_Click()`

Next, click off to the left and set a breakpoint on this line to verify the values are getting there!
`intPlayerScore = intPlayer1 + intPlayer2 + intDraw1 + intDraw2 + intDraw3`